# Why does <context:component-scan> not resolve Spring beans in an OSGi fragment bundle?

Tags: spring, osgi

I'm building a Spring 3, JSF 2, OSGi  (Virgo Tomcat 3.5.0.M03) application.

Currently I have a host web bundle, and a fragment bundle. 
The fragment bundle adds some `.xhtml` JSF pages (facelets) to the host. The JSF pages in the fragment have their own UI controllers (Spring beans bound to a commandButton using the action attribute).

I've configured Spring beans using `<context:component-scan base-package="my.scan.package" />` in my host (web app) bundle's `applicationContext.xml`.

Now although `context:component-scan` works for the host bundle (ie the Spring beans acting as UI controllers are discovered), it fails in case of the fragment bundle:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /flow-deployer-db.xhtml @20,50 action="#{uiControllerDb.deployFlow()}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'uiControllerDb' resolved to null
    com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:107)
```

So although a fragment is supposed to be part of the same classpath as its host, and the ui controller class is declared in the fragment as such:

```
package my.scan.package;
...
@Component("uiControllerDb")
public class UIControllerDb implements Serializable {
```

It fails to resolve the bean in the fragment (while working in the host bundle):

```
    <h:commandButton id="deployFlow" value="Deploy Flow" type="submit"
         action="#{uiControllerDb.deployFlow()}" />
```

Extract from host bundle's `MANIFEST.MF`

```
...
Bundle-SymbolicName: web.host
Bundle-Version: 4.0.0.alpha
Require-Bundle: org.glassfish.com.sun.faces
Import-Package: javax.naming,javax.sql
Import-Bundle: org.eclipse.virgo.web.dm;version="[3.0.2.RELEASE,4)"
Import-Library: org.springframework.spring;version="[3.0,3.1.1)"
Bundle-Name: Web Host bundle
Web-ContextPath: /webHost
```

Extract from fragment MANIFEST.MF:

```
Bundle-SymbolicName: my.fragment.bundle
Bundle-Version: 4.0.0.alpha
Import-Library: org.springframework.spring;version="[3.0,3.1.1)"
Fragment-Host: web.host;bundle-version=4.0.0.alpha
```

How do I get JSF to resolve the Spring beans in the fragment?
Any pointers are appreciated. Thanks.

faces-config.xml:

```
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">

<application>
    <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
</application>

</faces-config>
```

web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>org.eclipse.virgo.web.dm.ServerOsgiBundleXmlWebApplicationContext</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: ok, I found the answer. Since the Spring context is created on application startup, adding a fragment with Spring beans doesn't update the context. Bouncing the container (Virgo) seems to solve the issue -- the annotated beans in the fragment become part of the unified host-fragment context. Only I was expecting this to happen on deployment of the fragment as Virgo anyway refreshes (stops & restarts) the host bundle when the fragment is deployed.

Comment: Please post it as an answer and mark it as the correct answer, other users looking for answers to this questions will find it useful! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions

Comment: @Gabber: Will do, thanks. (Just tried & apparently I have to wait for 8 hours -- still disreputable :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer. 
Spring context is created on application startup - so adding a fragment with Spring beans doesn't update the context automatically.
Bouncing the container (Virgo) seems to solve the issue -- the annotated beans in the fragment become part of the unified host-fragment context.

Thing is, I was expecting this to happen on deployment of the fragment as Virgo anyway refreshes (stops & restarts) the host bundle when the fragment is deployed.